# Laravel 4 Resource perform action after default store

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have taken over a project which uses Laravel 4, and the previous developer created a RESTful resource in the routes file like so:

```
Route::resource('home/information', 'HomeInformationController',
    array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
```

Now, when I look in HomeInformationController.php I see some other methods the user created, but I do not see a **store** method, but when I make a post request to the resource, I get a successful 201 CREATED response. My question is, is there a way to perform another action without disturbing what it is already doing by default? I know I could implement a store method myself and do it that way, but I was wondering if there was a way to keep it the way it is and simply perform a default action every time a record is created.

Also, How is laravel even creating the record, since there is no store method? Does laravel create one by default when you create a resource? And how does it know which model use? There is indeed a model called HomeInformation.php. I have searched Laravel documentation but have not found anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course You can.
let's say You know the route:

```
Route::resource('home/information', 'HomeInformationController',
    array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
```

and You know that there are methods (in HomeInformationController) of REST excepting create and edit.

so You can create custom routes and use same controller or another controller.
for example:

```
Route::get('some/custom/route', array('uses' => 'HomeInformationController@existingMethodOrCustomMethod'));
Route::post('some/custom/route/that/handles/post', array('uses' => 'HomeInformationController@existingMethodOrCustomMethod2'));
```

and add to Your controller:

```
public function existingMethodOrCustomMethod(){/*implementation here*/}
public function existingMethodOrCustomMethod2(){/*implementation here*/}
```

with arguments:

```
Route::get('some/custom/route/{id}', array('uses' => 'HomeInformationController@existingMethodOrCustomMethod'));
Route::post('some/custom/route/that/handles/post/{id}', array('uses' => 'HomeInformationController@existingMethodOrCustomMethod2'));
```

and add to Your controller:

```
public function existingMethodOrCustomMethod($id){/*implementation here*/}
public function existingMethodOrCustomMethod2($id){/*implementation here*/}
```

read about routing here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing